# How to make the attribute list extendable in DTD file

Tags: java, dtd

I am wondering if you have any ideas of how to make the attribute type free in a dtd File for example

```
 <!ELEMENT Attribute (#PCDATA)>
  <ATTLIST name (code | permission)>
```

If for example i have several types of attribute name, that i can't specify all of them in the ATTLIST declaration.
How to modify the ATTLIST declaration so the xml file will still valid even if 
i have type not enumerated in the DTD for example

```
<Attribute name="code">30</Attribute>
<Attribute name="non_declared_name_type>"value"</Attribute>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `name` attribute on the `Attribute` element to match any of `code`, or `permission`, or any XML Name, then that amounts to saying you want it to match any XML Name.  The closest approximation using DTDs would be

```
<!ATTLIST Attribute name NMTOKEN #REQUIRED>
```

This declaration assumes the attribute should be required.

For such 'semi-closed' lists of values, which have some enumerated values but can accept others, there are in general two approaches when using DTDs.

(a) One can declare them as shown above, and make sure the users of the DTD are aware of the enumerated values, so that they use those when appropriate, and don't invent new ways of spelling those names, by listing the enumerated values in the documentation and/or adding a comment in the DTD itself:

```
<!--* Expected values include 
    *
    * 'code' (to be used when ... or ...)
    * 'permission' (to be used for ... and ...).
    *
    * Use other values only if necessary. *-->
<!ATTLIST Attribute name NMTOKEN #REQUIRED>
```

(b) One can split the attribute in two:  one for the known values, plus a special value like 'other', and one for other values.

```
<!ATTLIST Attribute 
          name (code | permission | other) #REQUIRED
          other_name NMTOKEN #IMPLIED >
```

This gets the enumerated values into the DTD explicitly, and allows software that uses enumerations to find them (and put them, for example, into selection lists in a user interface), while still allowing other values.  The use of undeclared values then becomes

```
<Attribute name="other" other_name="non_declared_name_type"
  >"value"</Attribute>
```

Comment: Thank you Sperberg for your answer, i used this syntax and it worked for me:
          <!ATTLIST Attribute name CDATA #REQUIRED>

 can you tell me from your experience what is the difference and what is better to use? ( surly yours but want to know advantages and understand why)

Comment: Any good introduction to XML should give you a good understanding of the differences between CDATA (which accepts any sequence of XML characters) and NMTOKEN (which accepts only characters legal in XML names).  For CDATA, values like `Hi, mom!` and `34 * 27 + 3.4` are valid; for NMTOKEN they are not, because blank, comma, exclamation point, asterisk, and plus are not Name characters.  My guess that you would do better to NMTOKEN is based on guessing that the attribute Attribute/@name is for.